# Data in table using ng-repeat disappears from page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage

I have created the following website:
http://expenseappusingangular.azurewebsites.net/

I have the following code for the spending details table at the very bottom of the page:

```
<section id="Details">
        <h2>Spending Details</h2>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Expense</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="expense in expenses | orderBy: 'date'">
                    <td>{{ expense.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ expense.text }}</td>
                    <td>{{ expense.category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ expense.amount > 0 ? '$' : ''}}{{ expense.amount }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>

function ExpenseController($scope) {
$scope.appTitle = "Expense App using Angular";
$scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('expenses');
$scope.expenses = (localStorage.getItem('expenses') !== null) ? JSON.parse($scope.saved) : [];
localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify($scope.expenses));

$scope.addExpense = function () {
    $scope.expenses.push({
        text: $scope.expenseText,
        category: $scope.categoryText,
        amount: $scope.amountText,
        date: $scope.dateText
    });
    $scope.expenseText = '';
    $scope.categoryText = '';
    $scope.amountText = '';
    $scope.dateText = '';
    localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify($scope.expenses));
};

$scope.countExpenses = function () {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.expenses, function (expense) {
        count += 1;
    });
    return count;
};

$scope.totalAmountByCategory = function (category) {
    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.expenses, function (expense) {
        sum += expense.category == category ? parseFloat(expense.amount) : 0;
    });
    return sum;
};

$scope.totalAmount = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.expenses, function (expense) {
        sum += expense.amount > 0 ? parseFloat(expense.amount) : 0;
    });
    return sum;
};}
```

After I enter in an expense or two, wait a few minutes, and then refresh the page, the data in the table at the bottom disappears but is still reflected in the category table and the chart.  I checked the local storage in the browser, and the expenses object is still there.

Do you have any idea why the values are disappearing from this bottom table?

Thanks!

Comment: _...wait a few minutes, and then refresh the page?_ Do you mean sometimes the data is not being loaded on initialization?

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well ? In which you fetching all the data on controller load ?

Comment: How are you reflecting/fetching data from localStorage?

Comment: Whenever I first load the page and click on the add button, the expenses are added to the spending details table and the category table as expected.  If I refresh the page, the chart and category table stay the same and have the right data.  The spending details table is empty.  When I try to add a new expense, the new expense doesn't show up in that bottom table.

Comment: I have added my controller code.

Comment: I just opened your page and the erros follows to this [angularjs page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=expense%20in%20expenses%20%7C%20orderBy:%20%27date%27&p1=object:004). Try `track by $index`.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I tried that, and it doesn't appear to fix the problem.

Comment: It would be: `expense in expenses | orderBy:'date' track by $index`

Comment: please add $scope.expenses = (localStorage.getItem('expenses') !== null) ? JSON.parse($scope.saved) : []; in a watcher to check if they are re rendered

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes That worked!  Thank you so much.